# what are the predefined templates in polymer starter kit?

Tags: templates, polymer, polymer-1.0, googleio, polymer-starter-kit

In the [IO presentation](https://youtu.be/fD2As5RmM8Q?t=38m1s) a speaker SUPER BRIEFLY talked about App Templates and how PSK1 has support for "navigation card layouts, navigation list details" and others. What're the details on these layouts? Where can I find more info on these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be what you are looking for - https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-layout-templates

Answer (score 0):

As of today, the [Polymer Start Kit](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/polymer-starter-kit/index?hl=en) itself doesn't provide multiple templates. It creates the scaffolding for a simple demo application that uses a side bar menu, page routes, and two simple custom elements for demo purposes. It also creates a bower development environment that is configured and ready to use out-of-the-box. If you new to either Polymer or bower it is big help. If you are new to both it is a huge time saver.